# SettingsService Where are the information saved?

Tags: template10

I where is the information save? is it in a file in local storage? 
I have use the example in template 10 template. 
like

```
public string ProdLanguage
{
    get { return _helper.Read<string>(nameof(ProdLanguage), "en"); }
    set {  _helper.Write(nameof(ProdLanguage), value); App.Lang = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appdata -> local -> packages -> {Install Folder GUID} -> Settings -> settings.dat